# Why does shorting a call option have potential for unlimited loss?

Tags: investing, options, risk, call-options, option-exercise

Referring to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_(finance), for a short call:

> If the stock price increases over the exercise price by more than the 
>   amount of the premium, the short will lose money, with the potential 
>   loss unlimited.

Assume the current stock price is $100, and I hold one stock. Then I sell a call option with a strike price of $100, expiring one year later, for a premium of $10.

So even if the stock price is $1000 a year later, I sell the stock at $100. I still earn the 10 bucks, so why am I going to have a loss? Even an unlimited loss? Is it about opportunity cost? I think it's unreasonable.

Comment: Note that in your example, you don't state what you paid for the stock. If you paid $400/share and sold it for $100/share then you'd have a loss whereas if you didn't write the call option you'd have a nice gain of $600/share.

Comment: Maybe i am not reading correctly, but the option consists of 100 shares of the stock, and you are only buying one share.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are likely making an assumption that the "Short call" part of the article you refer to isn't making: that you own the underlying stock in the first place. Rather, selling short a call has two primary cases with considerably different risk profiles. When you short-sell (or "write") a call option on a stock, your position can either be:

- *covered*, which means you **already own the underlying stock** and will simply need to deliver it if you are assigned,

  or else
- *uncovered* (or *naked*), which means you do **not** own the underlying stock.

Writing a covered call can be a relatively conservative trade, while writing a naked call (if your broker were to permit such) can be extremely risky.

Consider: With an uncovered position, should you be assigned you will be required to first buy the underlying **at the prevailing price** in order to be able to fulfil your contractual obligation to sell/deliver the underlying to the exercising option holder for the [lower] contract exercise price. This is a very real cost — certainly not an opportunity cost.

Look a little further in the article you linked, to the [Option strategies](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_(finance)#Option_strategies) section, and you will see the covered call mentioned there. That's the kind of trade you describe in your example.

Comment: +1 Nice answer Chris, I was about to write something very similar.

Comment: Nice Answer Chris, I was about to write something completely different, in a foreign language, wrong and opinionated.

Comment: @ssaltman LOL! esp. 'wrong'

Comment: "Writing a covered call can be a relatively conservative trade, "... while writing a naked call (if your broker were to permit such) can be extremely risky. Consider: With an uncovered position, should you be assigned you will be required to buy the underlying at the prevailing price."  BUY the underlying if assigned on a naked call?

Comment: @BobBaerker Yes, exactly. "Buy" is *not* a typo. In the naked short call case, the writer of the option contract that's been assigned would have to **buy** the underlying shares in the market, at the prevailing market price, in order to *then* sell/deliver the underlying to the exercising option holder, at the option contract price. But, you're right that my answer could be confusing without mention of the subsequent sale/delivery of those shares.

Comment: @Chris W. Rea - Yes, your description was confusing.   If the naked call seller is assigned and if shares are borrowable, there's no immediate forced buy requirement.  He sells the shares and ends up with a short equity position.  If he chooses to close the short share position, he then buys the shares to cover.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are selling a call option, you have to obligation to sell that stock at the agreed price.

If today's stock price is $100 and you sell a call option for ... let's say $102 and stock 'shoots' up: then you buy the stock at $102 and sell it to the new price. You are out of the pocket [new price - $102] * 100 * number of contracts.

They say UNLIMITED because they think that stock could go up to infinite, which is unrealistic. But stocks cannot go too much up ...